# Django Python noob - how do I get the NUMBER out of a Aggregate sum?

Tags: python, django, aggregate, annotate

I have a simple Aggregate:

```
    tot=PurchaseOrderLine.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('price'))
    return HttpResponse(tot)
```

This returns "total".

If I do:

```
    return HttpResponse(str(tot))
```

It displays `"{'total': Decimal('321.60')}"`

How do I get the NUMERIC var out of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tot=PurchaseOrderLine.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('price'))['total'] 
return HttpResponse(tot)
```